# Creating a class instance with parameters

Tags: c++, class, constructor

This is the constructor in the class:

```
Course(int courseId, Instructor instructor, string courseName, string dept) 
    : courseId(courseId)
    , instructor(instructor)
    , courseName(courseName)
    , dept(dept)
{ };
```

My problem is with the second argument Instructor instructor. What exactly does this mean because I have never seen mixing of two classes like this?

Comment: It means you need to have an `Instructor` object in order to create a `Course` (and a copy of that object will be stored in the created `Course` object)

Comment: ... same way as you need `std::string` instances ...

Comment: what's the problem in having Instructor object being passed in constructor? Also note you are passing Instructor object by value hence copy ctr for Instructor would be invoked here.

Comment: Can someone give a random example of what the constructor call would look like since it includes the Instructor object?

Comment: It makes it hard to read (kind of "ambiguous") when you have the same names for the arguments that you pass to the constructor and for the member variables of the class. If you can use different names for the arguments, then it will make the code easier to read and understand.

Comment: @barakmanos I tend to use the same name for both when the name is appropriate for both.

Comment: @barakmanos c++ **is** case sensitive, so what are you bothering about?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: The names here are identical case-wise!!!

Comment: @barakmanos Ah! I see, sorry. Yes, they are (parameter/member names). I personally use a notation like either class member name or parameter name is appended with a `_`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I personally use `m_` prefix for member variable names.

Comment: @barakmanos Mine's shorter ;) ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Mine is an acceptable convention ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means you need to pass an `Instructor` object to it, just as the first parameter means it takes an `int` object, and the third and fourth take `string` objects. For example:

```
int courseId = 0;
Instructor instructor; // Here we default construct an Instructor
std::string courseName = "Foo";
std::string dept = "Bar";

Course my_course(courseId, instructor, courseName, dept);
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^
//              Here the Instructor is being passed
```

That declaration of `instructor` will only work if `Instructor` has a default constructor, which I'm guessing it doesn't. If the constructor for `Instructor` has some parameters, then you need to pass them like so:

```
Instructor instructor(some, params, here);
```

Comment: In fact you should also mention this little naming clash problem, that was discussed by @barakmano and me right above.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't do it and I don't see a good reason to recommend it. I definitely won't recommend pre/postfixing member names! If you could come up with more appropriate names for either the parameters or the members, that would be fine, but sticking little symbols on member names is not very nice in my eyes. Their names do not need to distinguish them - they are already distinguished by being members.

Comment: OK you're right, since they (the members) are referenced from the initializer list, they're distinguished well.

Comment: @JosephMansfield [how to just declare `my_course` without calling its constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67550551)?