# How to just declare an object using a class with a constructor requiring parameters?

Tags: c++, syntax, g++, syntax-error, openmp

I have the following non thread safe code inside an Openmp for loop

```
bneijt::MetalinkFile record(filename, &mirrorList);
```

because the constructor at the same time updates `mirrorList` which is a vector used after the loop and thus has to be shared among all threads.
Where the `MetalinkFile` class is

```
class bneijt::MetalinkFile : public std::string {
  private:
    std::string d_filename;
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char const>> d_paths;
    const bneijt::MirrorList *d_ml;
    bool d_sizeSet;
    unsigned long long d_size;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >> d_vers;
    std::vector<std::string> d_verificationLines;

  public:
    MetalinkFile(const std::string &, const bneijt::MirrorList *);
    void setSize(unsigned long long);
    std::string size(void) const;
    void addVerification(const std::string &);
    void addVerification(const std::string &, const std::string &);
    void addPath(const std::string &, const std::string &);
    void addPath(const std::string &, const std::string &, unsigned char);
    void addPath(const std::string &, const std::string &, const std::string &);
    void finalize(void);
}
```

Of course, I thought about using

```
#pragma omp critical
{
    bneijt::MetalinkFile record(filename, &mirrorList);
}
```

which of course doesn’t work when the record is called in the parallel region after

```
In function 'int main(int, char**)':
src/main.cc:379:17: error: 'record' was not declared in this scope.
  379 |                 record.setSize(size);
```

And since doing

```
bneijt::MetalinkFile record;
#pragma omp critical
{
    bneijt::MetalinkFile record(filename, &mirrorList);
}
```

isn’t the right answer either

```
In function 'int main(int, char**)':
src/main.cc:287:30: error: no matching function for call to 'bneijt::MetalinkFile::MetalinkFile()'
  287 |                 MetalinkFile record;
      |                              ^~~~~~
In file included from src/Metalink/Metalink.hh:29,
                 from src/metalink.cc:49:
src/Metalink/../MetalinkFile/MetalinkFile.hh:55:17: note: candidate: 'bneijt::MetalinkFile::MetalinkFile(const string&, const bneijt::MirrorList*)'
   55 |                 MetalinkFile(std::string const &filename, MirrorList const *ml)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/Metalink/../MetalinkFile/MetalinkFile.hh:55:17: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
```

**What’s the correct way to declare a variable which is using a class with a constructor requiring arguments? I’m meaning, how to declare record without calling the MetalinkFile constructor?**

Comment: I know it’s a simple error, but would it be possible to have the answer anyway please?

Answer (score 1):

You can delay construction and keep the "destroyed after exits scope" semantics with types like `std::unique_ptr`(stores the instance behind a pointer) or `std::optional`(stores the object just like a normal instance).

So something like this with unique_ptr

```
std::unique_ptr<bneijt::MetalinkFile> record;
#pragma omp critical
{
    record.reset(new bneijt::MetalinkFile (filename, &mirrorList));
}
//example usage
record->setSize(500);
```

or this with std::optional.

```
std::optional<bneijt::MetalinkFile> record;
{
    record.emplace(filename, &mirrorList);
}
//example usage
record->setSize(500);
```